# Expression precedence in Irony parser

Tags: c#, parsing, expression, irony

Consider this portion of my vbscript grammar

```
EXPR.Rule = BINARY_EXPR 
        | COMPARE_EXPR
        | AND_EXPR
        | OR_EXPR;

BINARY_EXPR.Rule = EXPR + BINARY_OP + EXPR + ReduceHere();
COMPARE_EXPR.Rule = EXPR + COMPARE_OP + EXPR + ReduceHere();
AND_EXPR.Rule = EXPR + "and" + EXPR;
OR_EXPR.Rule = EXPR + "or" + EXPR;

COMPARE_OP.Rule = ToTerm("=") | "<=" | ">=" | "<" | ">" | "<>";
BINARY_OP.Rule = ToTerm("+") | "&" | "^" | "-" | "*" | "/" | "\\";// | "=" | "<=" | ">=" | "<" | ">" | "<>" | "mod" | "and" | "or";

RegisterOperators(60, "^");
RegisterOperators(50, "*", "/", "\\", "mod");
RegisterOperators(40, "+", "-", "&");
RegisterOperators(30, "=", "<=", ">=", "<", ">", "<>");
RegisterOperators(20, "and", "or");
```

and this vbscript program:

```
if 2=1+1 then x = 5
```

It's parsing this as `if (2=1)+1 then x = 5` instead of `if 2=(1+1) then x = 5`. I have `BINARY_EXPR` specified before `COMPARE_EXPR`  and "+" has a higher operator precedence so I can't figure out how to tell it that it should be looking for the addition operation first. How else can I express this so Irony will parse it the way I'm intending?

Comment: http://www.robusthaven.com/blog/parsing-expression-grammar/dsl-pair-programming-with-leblanc  might be helpful. I show how I solved a math expression which could be extended for your usecase. Source code is in NPEG nuget package.   Similar to what: 
@Tinctorius is suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never worked with Irony, but if it doesn't provide that functionality (or if you can't figure out how it works), you can always try to stratify your `EXPR` nonterminal.

Let's take only addition, subtraction, multiplication, parentheses, and comparison for example:

```
EXPR0.Rule = EXPR1
           | EXPR1 + "=" + EXPR1
           ;
EXPR1.Rule = EXPR2
           | EXPR1 + "+" + EXPR1
           | EXPR1 + "-" + EXPR2
           ;
EXPR2.Rule = EXPR3
           | EXPR2 + "*" + EXPR2
           ;
EXPR3.Rule = "(" + EXPR0 + ")"
           | USEVARIABLE
           | LITERAL
           ;
```

All operators with the same precedence live in their own stratum. They can't have operators of a lower precedence on their left- or right-hand side without running all the way through to `EXPR3`, which provides a loop back to `EXPR0`.

Note that `"-"` takes an `EXPR2` on its right-hand side. This is because it's a [right-associative operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity#Right-associativity_of_assignment_operators), while `"+"` is an associative operator. While `1 - 2 - 3` must always be interpreted as `(1 - 2) - 3`, `1 + 2 + 3` can be interpreted as both `(1 + 2) + 3` and `1 + (2 + 3)`. I'm not familiar enough with VB to say anything about the associativity of `"="`, so I've made it non-associative.

Again, I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, so the syntax might not be correct ;)